# Reading in a file, one chunk at a time

Tags: python, file

I have a VERY large file formatted like this:

```
(mydelimiter)
line
line
(mydelimiter)
line
line
(mydelimiter)
```

Since the file is so large I can't read it all into memory at once. So I would like to read each chunk between "(mydelimiter)" at a time, perform some operations on it, then read in the next chunk.

This is the code I have so far:

```
with open(infile,'r') as f: 
    chunk = []
    for line in f:
        chunk.append(line)
```

Now, I'm not sure how to tell python "keep appending lines UNTIL you hit another line with '(mydelimiter)' in it", and then save the line where it stopped abd start there in the next iteration of the for loop.

Note: it's also not possible to read in a certain number of lines at a time since each chunk is variable length.

Comment: Please link to any questions you believe I have duplicated. I have searched stackoverflow thoroughly before posting this question and not found an answer.

Comment: The link is at the top of the page, below your question's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you perhaps over thinking this? Something as simple as the following code can do the trick for you

```
with open(infile,'r') as f: 
    chunk = []
    for line in f:
        if line == 'my delimiter':
             call_something(chunk)
             chunk=[]
        else :
             chunk.append(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can you clarify what your call_something() function is doing here?

Comment: well call_something is a function that you define that works with your chunk of data

Comment: Yes, thanks!! Just accepted your answer (apologies for forgetting this!)

Comment: all the best with your project